# Ubuntu 18.04 fonts are very small

Tags: gnome, fonts

Hi I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04. However fonts on some programs are very small. For instance when I run Notepad++ texts like settings are incredibly small despite changing the font size from the menu. On Chrome or Spotify I can do CTRL++ and that works but it is not a correct solution because it is not system wide and in some programs that shortcut doesn't work. I tried changing fonts on Gnome Tweak Tool and that effected many programs and after changing the scaling from the gnome tweak tool now fonts on many programs are generally okay. However for programs like Notepad++ and Unity3D it doesn't work. I could make font 24 on tweak tool and font on tweak tool would be huge.Than when I go to let's say Notepad++ everything is still same. In Unity3D I can see that header texts like Window, Help etc is large now but all the other text is still very small. On all the other IDE's it works fine. Thanks for the help. I also enabled Large Text from Universal Access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fractional Scaling 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044065/fractional-scaling-18-04-lts)

Comment: DIsplay Scaling factor doesn't work.It makes everything way too big.Fonts are generally fine after the Gnome Tweak Tool scaling but some programs do not get effected or they get partially effected.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/859539/how-can-i-optimize-font-for-my-uhd-screen-in-unity/859565#859565 to issue `xrandr --dpi 144` and then call your program which doesn't follow hi resolution monitor rules.

Comment: I tried xrandr but not exactly sure where is notepad++ and Unity3D is located.For notepad++ i need wine but wine path is different than notepad++ path shown on the internet.

Comment: A little above my pay grade, but in general type `ps -aux` to see what is running before you start your app. Then start your app again and run `ps -aux` to see what is running now. The difference between the two is the process that started up. I assume though that you want to run `xrandr --dpi 144` before running `wine`?

Comment: What I mean is with combination of Large Text, bigger fonts and scaling many programs look okay.Just these two is the issue and I guess xrandr is program specific so it is okay.I want to run xrandr than launch the program so hopefully it would save the settings for that program.I need wine because notepad++ do not run on LInux.So i have to call it through wine.So yes xrandr than run notepad++ through wine hoepfully should work.Have no idea for Unity3D though.

Comment: I used to use `notepad` in the 90's and liked it. Could I suggest you try `gedit` when using Ubuntu for text editing? For more wordprocessing orientated tasks you could try LibreOffice Write.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I can perhaps find alternative to notepad++ however I still have to fix Unity as there is no alternatives to that unfortunately.

Comment: I've been struggling with the small-font problem in Kubuntu for quite a while.  I've found solutions that seem to work, but none of them are preserved over logout.  I have a specific test case: the website nytimes.com, viewed either in Firefox or in Chromium.  Does anyone know of a way to enlarge the image on that website that's preserved over logout?  If that one doesn't work, lots of others won't work either.